# Отслеживание сообщений Telegram ботом в других каналах и чатах Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Всем добрый день.
Пишу своего первого Телеграм бота на Node.js.
Задачу поставила следующую: считать количество всех соообщений от каждого пользователя чата.
Затем выводить топ самых активных пользователей.

На данный момент считаю сообщения только в приватном чате с самим ботом.
Добавила своего бота в чат с друзьями.

Слушаю сообщения с помощью:

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
// код
};
```

Данный метод не работает в чате с друзьями.
Только с приватном чате с самим ботом.

Доступ к сообщениям через botFather включила.

Как решить эту проблему?

Заранее благодарю за помощь!